# wrong parameters for exception

Tags: php, exception

I am getting the following error message:

> Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])

Here is my code:

```
class DAOException extends Exception {

function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null){
    parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
}
```

I try to make my own exception but it keep saying that i have an error at this line:

```
parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous).
```

Here is an example of when I could call this exception:

```
public function add(FilmDTO $filmDTO){
        try{
            $addPreparedStatement = parent::getConnection()->prepare(FilmDAO::ADD_REQUEST);
            $addPreparedStatement->bindParam(':titre', $filmDTO->getTitre());
            $addPreparedStatement->bindParam(':duree', $filmDTO->getDuree());
            $addPreparedStatement->bindParam(':realisateur', $filmDTO->getRealisateur());
            $addPreparedStatement->execute();
        } catch(PDOException $pdoException){
            throw new DAOException($pdoException->getMessage(), $pdoException->getCode(), $pdoException);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Furthermore my php version is 5.6

Comment: Post the full error.

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ecole\domain\exception\daoException.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br /> @PedroLobito

Comment: Post $pdoException->getMessage(), $pdoException->getCode(), $pdoException values respectively

Comment: @AnuragVerma I cant these functions come from PDO class.

Comment: What happen if you  replace `$pdoException->getCode()` with an integer ?

Comment: just echo those three elements in your code. It seems one of the three elements are not in their appropriate form.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the PDO exception can have a code that is alphanumeric, whereas the exception can only have an integer code. So at the point in the DAO constructor where you pass the code you've been given (the PDO code - a string) to the exception construct, it's not having it.

You can get around this by casting the code to an integer in your DAOException constructor. If you need the full string code (I'm not sure if it gives you any more helpful information) you can always append or prepend it to the message string (again, in the DAOException constructor)

Answer (score 0):

[The PDOException class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)::getCode() may return string:

> final public Exception::getCode ( void ) : **mixed**

And it does that, with error codes like `HY1234`

Use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` to get the code number `1234` without `HY`. Keep in mind that `filter_var` returns a string not an int and it may return false so have a default exception code for eg 0 like that:

```
class DAOException extends Exception {

function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null){

    //exception code coversion
    $code = filter_var($code, \FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ($code === false) {
        $code = 0;
    } else {
        $code = (int) $code;
    }

    parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
}
```

The problem with error code is not specific to the PDO exception but in general to all Exceptions see this question:

[PHP Exception::getCode() contradicts Throwable interface that it implements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234089/php-exceptiongetcode-contradicts-throwable-interface-that-it-implements)