# PHP Exception::getCode() contradicts Throwable interface that it implements

Tags: php, exception, pdo, interface, typing

I've found a contradiction I could not understand.

[Exception::getCode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php)

has this definition:

> **final** public Exception::getCode ( void ) : **mixed**

with description:

> Returns the exception code as **integer** in Exception **but possibly
>   as other type** in Exception **descendants** (for example as **string** in
>   PDOException)

but the [Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class implements [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) interface that defines:

> abstract public getCode ( void ) : **int**

So how for an example PDOException as a descendant of Exception could return **string** type with getCode() without violating the Throwable interface that defines return type as **int**?

Putting aside PDOException I don't think it would be possible even for the Exeption class to work with the getCode() : mixed

See proof:

```
<?php

interface Bar {
    public function getCode() : int;
}

class Foo implements Bar
{
    public function getCode()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}

$bar = new Foo;
echo $bar->getCode();
```

runnig the script above gives an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Foo::getCode() must be compatible
>   with Bar::getCode()

as expected.

Does anyone know why this is possible that Exception class implements Throwable interface but has a different implementation of getCode() and everything "works"?

Maybe it does not have a different implementation but if so then PDOException could not return any other type than int - proof:

```
<?php

interface Bar {
    public function getCode() : int;
}

class Foo implements Bar
{
    public function getCode() : int
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}

$bar = new Foo;
echo $bar->getCode();
```

gives an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Foo::getCode()
>   must be of the type int, string returned

that contradicts with the statement PDOException may return string as return of getCode()

Assuming PDOException::getCode() may return a **string** instead of **int** and PDOException extending RuntimeException that defines:

> public Exception::__construct ([ string $message = "" [, **int** $code = 0
>   [, Throwable $previous = NULL ]]]

then how to throw your own CustomException that extends from PDOException in case of getting string as error code from PDOException::getCode()?

example code that fails (for the example it always sets error code as string):

```
class CustomException extends \PDOException
{
    public function __construct($msg = '', $code = 0, $previous = null)
    {
        $code = 'CustomException error code as string: "$code"';
        parent::__construct($msg, $code, $previous);
    }
}

try {

    try {
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=not_existing_database;host=127.0.0.1';
        $user = 'dbuser';
        $password = 'dbpass';

        $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password, [\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION => true]);

    } catch (\PDOException $e){
        throw new CustomException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }

} catch (\Exception $e){
    echo 'Code: ' . $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for CustomException([string $message [, **long** $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]])

Example code tested with PHP 7.3.18 CLI.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It would make me wonder if the documentation is just wrong.

Comment: If you are asking "how", I think it is that `PDOException` is internal where OOP things can be broken down. If you are asking "why", in the [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41064) [reports](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51742) for it people say it was needed because some databases don't synthesize their errors as numerics, only strings.

Comment: For what it's worth:
`var_dump((new ReflectionClass('Throwable'))->getMethods()[1]);` gets you the `getCode` method in the `Throwable` interface.


`var_dump((new ReflectionClass('Throwable'))->getMethods()[1]->hasReturnType());`

returns `false` for me with php7.4, which would make me think that `getCode` does not in fact have a defined return type.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That would explain a lot, I could even treat that as a feature but how to convert the PDOException reliably into your own Exception then? I Added an example at the end.

Comment: @zeterain nice finding with Reflection I forgot about its capabilities in this case. Thank you for the investigation.